# Complexity O(n^3) vs O((logn)^4))

Tags: big-o

I would like to prove that
O(n^3) is bigger than O((logn)^4).

I thought that I can divide both powers with 4 so it is
O(n^0.75)  vs O(logn) but then I don't know how i can prove that (n^k) is bigger than O(logn) for k>0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [L'Hopital rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) to calculate the limit

[image]